# Remove red line numbers from ACM 2017 SIGCONF Template

Tags: line-numbering, acm, acmart

I'm using the ACM LaTeX template (http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) which puts red line numbers on the first page of the paper. Is there a simple command I can use to remove these?

[image: Example of Red Line Numbers]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just delete `review` from the `\documentclass` line.  Or put `review=false` there, which is the same thing.

Comment: If you are using the authordraft option, adding review=false is required to remove the red line numbers.

Comment: this answer saved_my_time. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `authordraft` from `\documentclass`

Before change  : `\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}`

After change   : `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`